# Kendo Multiselect i want to have 1 DataSource for the selecting options and 1 for the selected options

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

So basically i have a kendo multiselect where i use a datasource to show the options but i want to show to the user some preselected options based on another datasource.

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
   dataTextField: "text",
   dataValueField: "value",
   dataSource: dataforselection
   value: [],
   valuePrimitive: true,
   autoBind: false,
});
```

so how am i suppose fill the **value** with another datasource ?
so i can add or remove items to the preselected datasource.

the preselected datasource have some properties the same with the dataforselection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the data from both datasources ready, create a new datasource containing both of them. Then use this combined datasource as the datasource for the multiselect and the selected datasource as the value, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.117/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
<script>
let dataSourceForSelection = [{
    text: "text1",
    value: "1"
}, {
    text: "text2",
    value: "2"
}, {
    text: "text3",
    value: "3"
}];

let selectedDataSource = [{
    text: "text4",
    value: "4"
}, {
    text: "text5",
    value: "5"
}];

let combinedDataSource = [...dataSourceForSelection, ...selectedDataSource];

$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: combinedDataSource,
    value: selectedDataSource,
    deselect: function(e) {
      if (selectedDataSource.some((entry) => entry.value === e.dataItem.value)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but i dont want to add the selectedDatasource to the selectionDatasource . imagine that the selectedDatasource will always be part of selection datasource . i just want to add or remove objects from the selecteddatasource and send it back to server and client again

Comment: So you need the user to not be able to deselect any of the preselected options?

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to prevent the user from deselecting a preselected entry